# Can I use any language in the subdomain names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, subdomain

I want to support all the native languages in the sub-domain names. For example, [https://வணக்கம்blogs.example.co](https://xn--blogs-m5na4i9dyc2oc.example.co) or niñaneverknew.example.co.

When I'm using this as `வணக்கம்blogs` subdomain name. Browser is automatically converting it to punycode as xn--blogs-m5na4i9dyc2oc.

So I'm decoding it to unicode(xn--blogs-m5na4i9dyc2oc to வணக்கம்blogs) in our node server before fetching the data. And passing that also in the path of the https request.

```
const path = `/TakenSubdomains.json?orderBy="insensitiveName"&equalTo="${punycode.toUnicode(name))}"&limitToFirst=1&timeout=10s&auth=${firebaseAuthToken}`;

var options = {
    method: "GET",
    hostname: host,
    path: path,
    headers: {},
    maxRedirects: 20,
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
      var chunks = [];
      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });
      res.on("end", function (chunk) {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        const json = JSON.parse(body.toString());
        resolve(json);
      });
      res.on("error", function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        reject(error);
      });
    });
    req.end();
  });
```

I got "request path contains unescaped characters" error.

So I used javascript inbuilt method called "encodeURIComponent" to escaping all the reserved characters.

```
const path = `/TakenSubdomains.json?orderBy="insensitiveName"&equalTo="${punycode.toUnicode(name))}"&limitToFirst=1&timeout=10s&auth=${firebaseAuthToken}`;

var options = {
    method: "GET",
    hostname: host,
    path: encodeURIComponent(path),
    headers: {},
    maxRedirects: 20,
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
      var chunks = [];
      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });
      res.on("end", function (chunk) {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        const json = JSON.parse(body.toString());
        resolve(json);
      });
      res.on("error", function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        reject(error);
      });
    });
    req.end();
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used javascript inbuilt method called "encodeURIComponent" to escaping all the reserved characters.

But you used it on the whole path, not on the individual components. You should write

```
const path = `/TakenSubdomains.json?orderBy="insensitiveName"&equalTo="${encodeURIComponent(punycode.toUnicode(name))}"&limitToFirst=1&timeout=10s&auth=${encodeURIComponent(firebaseAuthToken)}`;
```

(Btw it's weird to see the query parameters wrapped in quotes, are those really necessary?)